# Wordpress - get_comment_author() returns anonymous

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have developed a wordpress plugin that inserts a JS script in the head of every page of the site. I am trying to pass a couple variables to the script (in PHP) such as the name, the email, and the website of the author of the comment, when there's a comment.

I have tried to use the get_comment_author(), get_comment_author_url() and get_comment_author_email() but it always returns "Anonymous", even if I just entered a name, website and mail adress when posting a comment.

Here is the code:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'insert_script');

function insert_script(){


  $name = get_comment_author();
  $website = get_comment_author_url();
  $email = get_comment_author_email();



    echo " <script type='text/javascript'>

                var _gigo= _gigo || {};
                _gigo['firstname'] = '' ;
                _gigo['lastname'] = '".$name."' ;
                _gigo['company'] = '".$website."' ;
                _gigo['email'] = '".$email."' ;
           </script>";
}
```

Do you know why the functions return an anonymous author and how I could fix it ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen on [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_author) page, you need to supply an ID to that function, or it needs to be inside the loop. Because neither is true in your case, it returns `anonymous`.

> Description
>   Retrieve the author of the current comment. If the comment has an empty comment_author field, then 'Anonymous' person is assumed. This function is meant to live inside of the WordPress loop.

```
Usage

<?php $author = get_comment_author( $comment_ID ); ?>
```

---

To get comments by post, you can use the [get_comments()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) function. You could use it as follows:

```
<?php
global $post; // get the current post
$postId = $post->ID; // get the current post ID
$comments = get_comments('post_id=' . $postId); // This gets all comments from current post
?>
```

You can check [the link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) on how you can use the output that follows.

If this is still unclear, let me know.

Comment: Hi @Sander Koedood, and thanks for your answer. How could I retrieve the comment ID ? I've seen that there's a function for that, get_comment_ID(); , but it doesnt seem to work "on it's own". For example, a user leaves a comment, giving his name email and adress, how do I retrieve the ID of the comment he just posted ?

Comment: I'd have to see the code to be able to answer that I'm afraid.

Comment: Here is a gist of the entire plugin:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6e5043b5a4e95cf2d679

Comment: I've updated my answer for you. I hope you can work it out like this.