# Wordpress - get_comment_author() returns "Anonymous" as author name

Tags: php, wordpress

## Note

I know there is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627526/wordpress-get-comment-author-returns-anonymous) on this topic. Unfortunately I could not find a solution for my usecase there. So I'm asking this question again.

## Situation

Comments made by users that are **not logged in** return "Anonymous" as the Author Name. Even if the corresponding field in the comment-form was filled.

## Code

This is how the authors name is displayed (from the `functions.php`)

```
<?php
    /* translators: 1: comment author url, 2: comment author name, 3: comment permalink, 4: comment date/timestamp*/
    printf( __( '%2$s schrieb am %4$s', 'buddypress' ), get_comment_author_url(), get_comment_author(), get_comment_link(), get_comment_date() );
?>
```

Files that might be helpful:

- /wp-content/themes/mytheme/[functions.php](https://gist.github.com/NilsDannemann/493760160fcd2047e5b94daa06e3f725)
- /wp-content/themes/mytheme/[comments.php](https://gist.github.com/NilsDannemann/a6174170846719099411bf6c3a681c27)
- /wp-includes/[comment-template.php](https://gist.github.com/NilsDannemann/5d2f89f61e1ce96fc07edca84e0d89e2)

I'm really not sure how to even find the issue.
My guess from reading similar questions on StackOverflow is, that I have to pass the comment ID to get_comment_author(). But I have no idea how to do this in this case.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using the globals array to set and access comment ID?                $GLOBALS["comment_id"] = whatever; then access it later $commentID = $GLOBALS["comment_id"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_comment_author()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_author/) returns "Anonymous" if `$comment->comment_author` is empty, or if the comment ID is not passed to the function (defaults to 0).

In your functions.php, try explicitly setting the ID:

```
$cID = $comment->comment_ID;
printf( __( '%2$s schrieb am %4$s', 'buddypress' ), get_comment_author_url($cID), get_comment_author($cID), get_comment_link($cID), get_comment_date('',$cID) );
```

If this doesn't work, then the name isn't being stored in `$comment->comment_author`

Comment: You where right. I've tried setting the ID like you mentioned, yet I still get "Anonymous".

Any advice where I might look now?

Comment: Have you tried contacting support for the theme author?

Comment: Yes. The theme is no longer in development. Also I changed so many things, that it's pretty much my theme now. Maybe I'll just hire someone to fix this particular issue. But many thanks for your help anyway! :-)

Comment: It appears that the name is just not being passed to $comment->comment_author

Comment: Okay, it took a while, but in the end your answer let me to the solution. Brilliant me from the past thought it would be an awesome idea to remove the id's from the input fields on the comment form. Go me. -.-

Comment: Glad it's working for you! The only thing I'd add then, in the future, you should include ALL your code, including the form inputs. It would've made things much easier/quicker to resolve if those helping you have the whole picture. Cheers!